# Why are leafy green vegetables safe for snails given their high copper content?

Tags: aquarium, diet, snails

I've frequently seen leafy green vegetables like kale recommended as food for snails (in part due to their high calcium content). However, I was reading the nutritional content for several kinds of greens and noticed that many of them, such as kale and beet greens, also contain high amounts of copper, which I thought was actually toxic to snails. That being said, why are these safe foods for them?

Comment: related https://www.myfooddata.com/articles/high-copper-vegetables.php#high-copper-vegetables-list copper is 0,0002 g in 100 grams of spinach.

Comment: @trondhansen So, even if it's relatively high in copper compared to other foods, it's still low in absolute terms?

Comment: that is correct and it only means you should limit the amount you give each day and suplement with other vegetables that contain less copper,moderation is the way to do it no matter what pet it is.